# 2D/3D array constructor

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to create a class called `A` which, during instantiation, give me `2D` or `3D` array of `ints`. If I call `A(2)` I should get object `Arr[10,10]` and when I call `A(3)` I should get `Arr[10,10,10]`. I don't care at this point what the elements are.

When I tried this:

```
class A
{
    public object Arr;
    public A(int dim)
    {
        switch (dim)
        {
            case 2:
                object Arr = new int[10, 10];
                break;
            case 3:
                object Arr = new int[10, 10, 10];
                break;
            default:
                object Arr = null;
                break;
        }
    }      
}
```

I got this:

> CS0128    A local variable named 'Arr' is already defined in this scope.

When I tried this:

```
class A
{
    public object Arr;
    public A(2)
    {
        object Arr = new int[10, 10];
    }
    public A(3)
    {
        object Arr = new int[10, 10, 10];
    } 
}
```

I got this:

> CS1001    Identifier expected

I'm short of ideas now.

Can I do this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this:

> CS0128 A local variable named 'Arr' is already defined in this
>   scope.

Because you are defining again `object Arr` inside each `case`. It should just be `Arr = new int[10, 10, 10];`

In the second example in which you get this:

> CS1001 Identifier expected

My guess is what you really want is to instantiate the public `Arr` attribute of the class `A`. So you probably want something like this:

```
this.Arr = new int[10, 10];
```

Inside each constructor.

More about this `CS1001 Identifier expected`. It is because the signature of the method is expecting a variable, and you are passing `2` and `3`, and I guess what you want there is `int n`?

Comment: The second one fails because a constructor signature expects a type and name for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is incorrect because you don't need two `Constructor`. You just need one `Constructor` in your case and just use `Switch-Case` like this (don't define again `Arr` inside each case):

```
public class A
{
    public object Arr;
    public A(int dim)
    {
        switch (dim)
        {
            case 2:
                 Arr = new int[10, 10];
                break;
            case 3:
                 Arr = new int[10, 10, 10];
                break;
            default:
                 Arr = null;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
A obj1 = new A(2);
var x = obj1.Arr;//int[10,10]
A obj2 = new A(3);
var y = obj2.Arr;//int[10,10,10]
```